# Cloudflare - no CF-Cache-Status - is it caching or not?

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I'm running `curl` on a resource on the server that is using Cloudflare as it's CDN. However, I'm not sure if it's caching or not.

Here's the output from `A` - This is the one I'm not sure is caching:

`Resource A:`

```
< HTTP/1.1 530 
< Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 12:47:06 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: close
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=<numbers>; expires=Thu, 22-Mar-18 12:47:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.<domain>; HttpOnly
< Cache-Control: max-age=6
< Expires: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 12:47:12 GMT
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: <numbers>-LHR
```

`Resource B:` - this is clearly caching as it has a `CF-Cache-Status: HIT` header

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 12:47:56 GMT
< Content-Type: image/png
< Content-Length: 3853
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=<numbers>; expires=Thu, 22-Mar-18 12:47:56 GMT; path=/; domain=<domain>; HttpOnly
< Cf-Bgj: imgq:100
< Cf-Polished: pngoptimizer, origSize=5384
< Etag: "<etag>"
< Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Mar 2017 00:07:20 GMT
< X-Amz-Id-2: <numbers>=
< X-Amz-Meta-S3b-Last-Modified: 20170316T132941Z
< X-Amz-Request-Id: <numbers>
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< Expires: Wed, 22 Mar 2017 13:47:56 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: <numbers>-LHR
```

Note I've run these `curl` requests several times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Cloudflare is always using cache unless you have enabled the `developer mode` wich will disable caching.

Answer (score 4):

CloudFlare [does not cache HTML resources by default](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-). Since Resource A has `Content-Type: text/html`, it is likely a .html file and therefore is not cached.

Images, however, are cached by default. That's why the Content-Type of image/png (likely actually a .png file) of Resource B shows `CF-Cache-Status: HIT`.

Note that CloudFlare caches based on file extension, not by MIME type. So, without seeing the full url of your requests with their file extensions, I am only assuming that the extensions of resources A and B actually match the MIME type in the curl responses.

If you want to cache HTML files, you can [configure page rules](https://collinmbarrett.com/wordpress-cloudflare-dynamic-caching/) to do so.

I hope that helps!

Comment: #facepalm. when you Google a question and land on an SO question with your own answer...

Comment: Aside: You can also use https://cf-cache-status.net to check if your resources is cached properly.